# Login loop unlike any other

Tags: login, lightdm

I can't get beyond the graphical login screen since I ran `apt-get upgrade` on my brand new Ubuntu Dell with Ubuntu 14.04

The permissions on `.Xauthority`, `.ICEauthority`, and `/tmp` are correct. Reinstalling lightdm did not help; I tried that three times in various variants. Switching over to gdm caused a black-screen nightmare that took me half an hour to solve, and I'm back to lightdm. I installed `linux-generic`, and it didn't help. That exhausts everything suggested on this site. I have an nvidia card. Any idea what I can do?

Here is the content of `.xsession-errors`:

```
init: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2195) terminated with status 1
init: unity-settings-daemon main process (2182) killed by TERM signal
init: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
init: logrotate main process (2097) killed by TERM signal
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/lightdm.0.crash) main process (2130) killed by TERM signal
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_software-properties-gtk.1001.crash) main process (2131) killed by TERM signal
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_unity-control-center.1001.crash) main process (2133) killed by TERM signal
init: xsession-init main process (2173) killed by TERM signal
init: hud main process (2189) killed by TERM signal
init: unity-panel-service main process (2197) killed by TERM signal
```

I have resinstalled Ubuntu twice to fix various problems, but the login loop happens every time, except for the first login after each installation.

And this is the result of `grep -i nvidia` in /var/log/Xorg.0.log

```
[    74.238] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    74.238] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  375.66  Mon May  1 14:28:39 PDT 2017
[    74.238] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    74.238] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    74.239] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    74.239] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    74.239] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  375.66  Mon May  1 14:03:26 PDT 2017
[    74.239] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    74.239] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[    74.251] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
[    74.251] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
[    74.251] (EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
[    74.383] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
```

Comment: "exhausts everything" eh? what about the nvidia specific answers like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/650253/527764) (4th answer to the canonical post)

Comment: I got one of those things immediately after upgrading my Nvidia driver and downgrading my Nvidia driver back to the previous version fixed it.

Comment: Thanks! I added the nvidia errors above. I wonder whether this is a secureboot/3rd party issue, or whether ubuntu upgraded the nvidia driver to something that no longer works. Any idea what nvidia driver I should have?

Comment: @karel What nvidia driver version do you have? Thanks!

Comment: Because you may have a problem with the Nvidia driver, try *nvidia-current* from the default Ubuntu 14.04 repositories.

Answer (score 2):

What @Zanna and @karel suggested works! I followed the link by Zanna and installed the `nvidia-375` driver. I don't know whether that's the same as nvidia-current from default Ubuntu 14.04, but it may well be. It asked me to reboot and disable secureboot. These instructions are ambiguous/confusing, but I managed to disable it. Now I can log in! Thanks!! I just hope the next auto-upgrade will not overwrite this.

Comment: apt has 2 features called `apt-mark hold` and `apt-mark unhold` **hold** is used to mark a package as held back, which will prevent the package from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed. **unhold** is used to cancel a previously set hold on a package to allow all actions again. **showhold** is used to print a list of packages on hold in the same way as for the other show commands. Also after 48 hours have elapsed you can mark your own answer as accepted by clicking the gray checkmark next to it which changes its color to green.